# Duda de sintaxis de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me apoyaron con el siguiente código.
Es para trabajar con LinkedList en Python.
Sin embargo no se que es lo que hace la siguiente declaración.

```
ret = curr = ListNode(0)
```

Que hace Python con doble asignación?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**En general:**
Si usamos de ejemplo:

`uno = dos = 0`

Hace que tanto `uno` como `dos` tengan valor de cero.
Funciona, pero es básicamente una manera algo tonta de ahorrar una linea, porque es igual de valido escribirlo en la misma linea que hacer esto:

```
uno = 0
dos = 0
```

Sin embargo, escribirlo en la misma linea es posible, ¿por qué? Simplemente es un efecto secundario del funcionamiento de los operadores. No tiene mayor misterio que eso.

A efectos practicos, puede crear situaciones complicadas debido a la asignación de valores de forma paralela, especialmente en compiladores que necesitan entender el código sin confundirse, por lo que se recomienda nunca utilizar esa sintaxis y es considerada una mala practica. Cualquier otro tipo de asignación sería más válido, incluso:

```
uno, dos = 0, 0
```

**Nota sobre Python:** Especificamente, la asignación paralela puede referenciar al mismo objeto desde dos variables diferentes, de manera que los cambios se reflejen en ambas variables. Esto suele dar problemas en un futuro para tipos de datos mutables como `listas` o `diccionarios`.

```
a = b = [0, 1, 2]  # Asignamos esa lista a A y B
a[0] = 100  # Cambiamos el valor solo de A

print(a)  # [100, 1, 2]
print(b)  # [100, 1, 2]
```

Como puedes ver, también se ha cambiado el valor en B.

Puedes leer más sobre esto aquí: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/